# An Interesting question based on an infinite sum and a set of points.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

Let x be a real number satisfying:$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{\left(2i+1\right)}}{\left(2i+1\right)!}\cdot\left(-1\right)^{i-1}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}.$$
Also, let $\left(X_{i,}Y_i\right)$(Where i is a positive integer) be a set of all distinct points satisfying:$$0\le Y_i\le \sqrt{1-X_i^2}$$Let:$$P=\left(0,\sqrt{\dfrac{\left(1+\cos x\right)}{2}}\right)\\Q=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{i=0}^n\dfrac{X_i}{n},\sum _{i=0}^n\dfrac{Y_i}{n}\right).$$
Prove that $PQ=0$.

---

I have realized that the first condition is of the form $x-\sin x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ using the MacLaurin series and that the second condition describes a semicircle with radius 1 centred at the origin. But I have no clue as to how to proceed.

An insight on how to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks.☺☺☺

Comment: By $PQ=0$ do you mean $P=Q$?

Comment: The length of the line joining PQ=0.,Yes

Comment: The first condition is $x - \sin x = \pi/2$; your difference is reversed.  Also, "Maclaurin series" (or, archaically, "M'Laurine" or "MacLaurin").

Comment: Thanks for the corrrections.

Comment: Are $(X_i, Y_i) \in \Bbb{R}^2$, ${}\in \Bbb{C}^2$, or taken from some other set?

Comment: both Xi and Yi are real.Hence the semicircle.

Comment: As it is, the question is missing an additional hypothesis on the existence of the limits in the definition of $Q$. Both sequences may diverge.

Comment: Notice that the statement implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1/n)\Sigma_{i \le n} X_i = 0$ for **any** sequence $\{X_i\}_{i \ge 1} \subset [-1,1]$, which is clearly false.

Comment: Why is it false, It is clear that if n tends to infinity, for every Xi there is a mirror coordinate with a negative sign. This the sum of all these pairs results in a total sum of 0.

Comment: Remember that its a semicircle

Comment: @N-N What "mirror coordinates"? I don't see **any** restriction on the $X_i$ other than being numbers in $[-1,1]$. It's easy to find examples where the sequence in the definition of $Q$ diverges. Additionally, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = L$  then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1/n)\Sigma_{i \le n} X_i = L$ too.

Comment: For every (Xi,Yi) satisfying the condition (-Xi,Yi) satisfies it as well.

Comment: It follows that sum of all Xi is 0

Comment: Now it remains to prove that the y coordinates are equal.

Comment: As I said in my first comment: you are missing some very important hypothesis regarding the sequences. The statement is **not** true in general. Consider $(X_i, Y_i) = (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ for all $i$. These points satisfy all the hypothesis but $Q = (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) \neq P$

Comment: The statement "let $(X_i,Y_i)$ be a set of all distinct points [on the semicircle]" is a little confusing. For one thing $(X_i,Y_i)$ doesn't look like a set, it looks like a point. I *guess* you meant some set of points indexed by $i$. From your summations, it appears you intend $i$ to range over integers. But integers are *countably* infinite, whereas the set of points on the semicircle is *uncountably* infinite, so there's no way for an integer-indexed set to contain all the semicircle points. You seem to have something in mind that your conditions, as stated, just aren't quite capturing.

Comment: Perhaps you mean, for a given $n$, let $(X_i,Y_i)$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n$ be the set of points on the "semipolygon" inscribed in the semicircle; specifically, define $(X_i,Y_i) := (\cos(i\pi/n),\sin(i\pi/n))$. Then your definitions of $P$ and $Q$ make sense and it's at least clear that the $x$-coordinate of $Q$ is zero. The problem reduces to showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^nY_i=\sqrt{\frac12(1+\cos x)}$ for your $x$ ... which may-or-may-not be true, I haven't looked. I'm not even sure if I'm captured your intention properly. Am I close?

Comment: @Sam How can you say that Q = (Xi,Yi), Remember that it is the average of all x and y coordinates satisfying the condition, and not just a single point.

Comment: @Blue As n tends to infinity won't it encompass all the points satisfying the inequality.Also Xi and Yi are real.And I have also realised that the conditions of Q implies that it denotes the "centre of mass" of the semicircle ,which is indeed a real converging coordinate.

Comment: Remember Yi is less than or equal to, therefore not lying on but inside the semicircle.

Comment: Im sure that at infinity all the points can be assigned an index which corresponds to an integer.

Comment: @Sam ,You are assuming that the point you have chosen is the only point satisfying the condition.

Comment: @Sam,In your second comment you say that  "limn→∞(1/n)Σi≤nXi=0 for any sequence {Xi}i≥1⊂[−1,1]," Which implies that Xi can have any value how many ever times it wants that value, that is clearly false. You fail to account for this":For every (Xi,Yi) satisfying the condition (-Xi,Yi) satisfies it as well."Also each point occurs exactly once, thus they form pairs.

Comment: @N-N: *"As n tends to infinity won't it encompass all the points satisfying the inequality."* No. *"Im sure that at infinity all the points can be assigned an index which corresponds to an integer."* Again, no. Points on the semicircle are uncountable; integers are countable. There is no one-to-one correspondence. (See, for instance, the Wikipedia's ["Uncountable Set" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set).) My semi-polygon vertices appear at rational fractions of $\pi$ along the semicircle, which doesn't account(!) for all of them. (continued)

Comment: But what about those inside the polygon?

Comment: @N-N: (continuing) *However*, for what you're trying to accomplish, I don't think it matters that you aren't actually getting every point in the semicircle. As $n\to\infty$, the semipolygon very closely approximates the semicircle. (This is an aspect of the rational numbers being "dense" in the real numbers, which is too much to go into here.) Unless I'm missing a nuance (I might be; it's late ;), the center of mass for the "infinite semipolygon" *should* match that of the semicircle, so the upshot of your argument (probably) remains intact. (continued)

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that is the intention of the question, Thanks a lot.☺

Comment: @N-N: (continuing) You can avoid these complexities by ignoring the $(X_i,Y_i)$ points and $Q$ completely, and stating simply that you believe $P$ is the center of mass of the semicircle, which should be straightforward to check. (Oh, but: be clear about what you mean by "center of mass". Is it the center of mass for the semicircular *area*? Or the center of mass for the semicircular *circumference*?)

Comment: I just wrote the question as it was. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Definitely  area since its less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the points satisfying: $X_i^2+Y_i^2\le 1\ $

This denotes a semicircular region.[image]

Q can be understood as being the average of all points or the centre of mass of the semicircle.

Let the COM be at a distance of k from the origin. Draw a line parallel to the diameter passing through the COM. Let $\theta$ be the central angle of this chord.

By the definition of a centre of mass,

Area above the chord = Area below the chord

2(Area of sector)=Area of semicircle

$$\begin{array}{l}2\left(\frac{r^2\theta }{2}-\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin \theta \right)=\frac{\pi r^2}{2}\\\Rightarrow \theta -\sin \theta =\frac{\pi }{2}\end{array}$$

By expanding using the Taylor Series we observe that $\theta$ = x

Therefore, Distance between origin and COM = k = r cos($\theta$/2)=$\begin{array}{l}\sqrt{\frac{\left(1+\cos x\right)}{2}}\end{array}$ $$\begin{array}{l}COM=\left(0,\sqrt{\frac{\left(1+\cos x\right)}{2}}\right)=P\end{array}$$

Hence P=Q or PQ=$0$.